# Animation on top of uiviewcontroller like facebook app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, animation

The new facebook app has a new feature. There is a little circle in the bottom of a message that means where is the user in the conversation. (hist last seen message).

It is pretty awesome, but i couldn´t figure out how it was developed. I´m pretty sure they created a new cell type, to show where is each user in the conversation. And then, if the user reads it, it just update the table and the user will be in another message that he just read. This would be ok.

But my question is, during this transition, the little circle is animated from the current message to the new position, and the others little circle are animated to make space for the new coming little circle. How is that possible? To animate something on top of a listview?

Thanks in regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give me a screenshot of what you're talking about so I can look at it, or give steps to get to the screen you're talking about?

Facebook does some pretty remarkable stuff with iOS. If you want to see some of the crazier things, check out the app Paper that was developed using the [Pop Framework.](https://github.com/facebook/pop) In there you might find some of the UI actions you're looking for.

Comment: I´ve seen the Pop Framweork app. But it is not that.. =(
As this screenshot shows (https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CDqoqJ_WEAAumQF.png) there´s the little circular face of the guy who is talking with in the bottom right side of the cell, and as you send message and the anoter user reads, the circular slides on top of the uitableviewcells